# DateTimePicker not setting the field value which is passed

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I am using [date_time_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker) and trying to set the date in date picker input field but it is not setting that value which is being passed instead it always set my current date.

Here is my code snippet.
This is the datetime picker input field.

```dart
DateTimePicker(
  type: DateTimePickerType.date,
  dateMask: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
  controller: startDateTxt,
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 5 * 365)),
  initialDate: initStartDate,
  icon: Icon(Icons.event),
  dateLabelText: 'Start Date',
  onChanged: (val) => setState(() => startDateTxt.text = val),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please fill this field';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (val) => setState(() => startDateTxt.text = val ?? ''),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Start Date",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    contentPadding:
        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 15),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.5))),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2))),
  ),
),
```

An I am setting the date like this.

```dart
startDateTxt.text = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd')
    .format(DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(cat.startDate));
endDateTxt.text = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd')
    .format(DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(cat.endDate));
setState(() {
  eventCatSelected = true;
  initStartDate = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').parse(startDateTxt.text);
  initEndDate = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').parse(endDateTxt.text);
});
```

When I run this code it always show my current date in input field, not that one which I am setting using above code.

Answer (score 0):

Update: To show initialValue you need to provide string on `initialValue`

```dart
DateTimePicker(
  initialValue: initDate.toString(), ///this
```

Demo Widget

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late DateTime initDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDate = DateTime.now();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DateTimePicker(
        initialValue: initDate.toString(),
        type: DateTimePickerType.date,
        firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 4)),
        lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 5 * 365)),
        initialDate: initDate,
        dateLabelText: 'Start Date',
        onChanged: (val) {},
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please fill this field';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same result even after that.

Comment: did you try with removing controller?

Comment: Yes, with or without controller, it is giving same result.

Comment: are you trying get update value while dialog is visible?

Comment: I am trying to set an initial date in this input field.

Comment: try update answer, using `initialValue: initDate.toString(),`

Comment: initDate cannot bet set as String. It is of type DateTime

Comment: `initDate` is `DateTime` and `initialValue` takes nullable String

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Can try running demo widget  `MyApp` . `runApp( MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));`